# Need explanation on how interface object is created in java-8 for lambda

Tags: lambda, interface, java-8

I am new to functional programming in java. Found this code at [here.](http://www.dummies.com/programming/java/how-to-use-lambda-expressions-in-java-8/)

I was wondering what is happening at:

```
Ball b = () -> { System.out.println("You hit it!"); };
```

is interface getting instantiated??

**Complete example** :

```
public class LambdaBall {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Ball b = () -> { System.out.println("You hit it!"); };
  b.hit();
 }

 interface Ball {
  void hit();
 }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to try the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) rather than an arbitrary web source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the old anonymous class way of initializing interfaces

```
Ball b = new Ball() {
   public void hit(){
       System.out.println("You hit it!"); 
   }
}
```

lambas do this instead

```
Ball b = () -> System.out.println("You hit it!");
```

and both are the same

Comment: Thank you Ash...
Since this is a functional interface 
    System.out.println("You hit it!")

is the actual implementation of the hit() method, and when b.hit is called; it gets execute.

Answer (score 2):

Before Java 8, the anonymous way to define a method of an interface was

```
Ball b = new Ball() {
   @Override
   public void hit(){
       System.out.println("You hit it!"); 
   }
}
```

Since the inception of Java 8, you can pass a function definition to a function.

```
Ball b = () -> System.out.println("You hit it!");
```

The above line lazily defines the hit() of Ball interface. Note should be given here that this is lazily evaluated. Remove the line `b.hit();` and you will noticed "You hit it!" doesn't get print in the console at all.
However, this is a naive example and you should avoid writing System.out.println() or simply saying polluting your environments with side effects inside functional code. Try making your function as [pure](https://www.sitepoint.com/functional-programming-pure-functions/) as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas Requires Target type which is provided by the Functional Interface That's why lambdas are used in pair with Functional interfaces.
**When a lambda expression occurs in a target type context, an instance of a class is automatically created that implements the functional interface. 

Note: type of interface should compatible with type of lambda**
Reference:- [Java Complete Reference 9th Edition jdk8](http://staff.cs.psu.ac.th/iew/cs344-481/Java%20The%20Complete%20Reference%20Ninth%20Edition.pdf)